# Rails4 - How to create a HTML button for a link?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, erb

I have the following link for account activation. The view does not have bootstrap.

```
<%= link_to "Activate", edit_account_activation_url(@user.activation_token,email: @user.email) %>
```

I want a button instead of a link.
How do I put account activation link in the action attribute of the form?

```
<form action="Account_Activation_Link_Here">
 <input type="Submit" value="Activate Account">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

you are looking for `button_to`

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to

```
<%= button_to "Activate", edit_account_activation_url(@user.activation_token,email: @user.email) %>
```

should do what you want.

Comment: make sure the http method is post for the url you are trying to submit via button. Because button_to helper by default trigger in post method.

Comment: @Doon I am getting NoMethodError in Rails::MailersController#preview when i add button_to

Comment: @Doon Yes from my view. app/views/user_mailer/account_activation.html.erb

Comment: are you getting a no method on the button_to or something else?  since unless you have changed something #preview shouldn't render acccount_activation.html.erb ?